# Indesign SDK: Compilation error while trying to compile the resource file with a existing boss class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, adobe-indesign

I have added a Boss class in the resource file as below, but facing below error while building the project in Visual studios 2010.

DocWch.fr(87): error R32691: # Error: **Custom type name expected, but 'kGTTxtEdtResponderServiceBoss' found.**

Below is the code snippet code where class is added:

resource ClassDescriptionTable(kSDKDefClassDescriptionTableResourceID)
{{{
    class
         {

```
  kGTTxtEdtResponderServiceBoss, 
    kInvalidClass,
    {

        IID_IK2SERVICEPROVIDER, kDocWchServiceProviderImpl,

        IID_IRESPONDER, kDocWchResponderImpl,
    }
     }
```

},

Answer (score 0):

The resource compiler does not know the mentioned identifier.
You must include the ID.h file that declares the ID:

```
#include "GTTxtID.h"
```